# Processos vazios na fila - PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, processo

Olá.

Essa semana começamos a ter um problema de processos vazios na fila do PostgreSQL, só que diferentemente dos outros processos, esses ficam travados. Isso está causando bastante lentidão no sistema.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de saber do que se tratam esses processos e se tem alguma forma de evistar que isso aconteça.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Esses *processos vazios* podem ser operações realizadas a partir de uma `ROLE` diferente da usada para fazer a sua consulta. Ou seja, você não possui privilégios para visualizar as operações realizadas por outros *usuários* do sistema.

A sugestão é usar uma `ROLE` de superusuário para fazer esse tipo de consulta, o que vai te dar poder total para saber o que está acontecendo.

Comment: Vou ver e te aviso.